# How use proxy with login and password in Selenium C# (ChromeDriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I try to use proxy with Authentication, but i have problems.
I try to use this code:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--proxy-server=http://" + "login:pass@IP:Port"); 
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://2ip.ru/");
```

But browser say me: `"ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES"`.
Proxy is ok. How can i solve this problem?

P.s. Also I try use this code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
proxy.HttpProxy =
proxy.SslProxy = "IP:Port";
proxy.SocksPassword = "pass";
proxy.SocksUserName = "login";
options.Proxy = proxy;
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
var chromedriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```